# Python Tests Failing while Installin

Tags: python

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and while installing Python 3.5.1 , after running make test I got the following error.

```
3 tests failed again:
    test_httplib test_ssl test_urllibnet
```

**test_urllibnet**

```
    test test_urllibnet failed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/test/test_urllibnet.py", line 100, in test_getcode
    self.assertEqual(code, 404)
AssertionError: 500 != 404
```

**test_httplib**

```
    test test_httplib failed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/test/test_httplib.py", line 1325, in test_networked_good_cert
    h.request('GET', '/')
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/http/client.py", line 1083, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/http/client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/http/client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/http/client.py", line 911, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/http/client.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/http/client.py", line 1237, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/ssl.py", line 376, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/ssl.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/ssl.py", line 983, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/ssl.py", line 628, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

**test_ssl**

```
Resource 'sha256.tbs-internet.com' is not available
/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/unittest/case.py:628: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.0.9', 42188), raddr=('82.94.164.164', 443)>
  outcome.errors.clear()
/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/unittest/case.py:628: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.0.9', 42198), raddr=('82.94.164.164', 443)>
  outcome.errors.clear()
/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/unittest/case.py:628: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.0.9', 42213), raddr=('82.94.164.164', 443)>
  outcome.errors.clear()
/home/user/Softwares/Python-3.5.1/Lib/unittest/case.py:628: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.0.9', 42235), raddr=('82.94.164.164', 443)>
  outcome.errors.clear()
test test_ssl failed -- multiple errors occurred; run in verbose mode for details
```

Will it affect in future if I proceed with installation? 
Any reason for this? Any solution to correct this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this looks like there is a problem with internet connectivity from your host. try

```
wget http://www.google.com
```

and see if you get any results.

ANSWER:

Looks like I found the issue: It's a bug in test.py from 2015 [psf.upfronthosting.co.za/issue25674](http://psf.upfronthosting.co.za/issue25674) I would recommend you get or reinstall Python from a new location, this bug was patched

Comment: tried it, no connectivity problem . Downloaded the index page after running the command
===============================================


Connecting to www.google.co.in (www.google.co.in)|216.58.197.67|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

    [ <=>                                   ] 12,785      --.-K/s   in 0.01s   

2016-05-11 00:40:04 (1.21 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [12785]

Comment: Looks like I found the issue: It's a bug in test.py from 2015 http://www.psf.upfronthosting.co.za/issue25674 I would recommend you get or reinstall Python from a new location, this bug was patched